# NSExpression catch invalid arguments

Tags: objective-c, invalid-argument, nsexpression

I am using NSExpression to evaluate a mathematical string and it works great. However I want to have a way of catching an error when the input string is invalid, such as "3++2". Is there a way to go about doing this instead of the application terminating due to 'NSInvalidArgumentException'. Sorry, I am fairly new to objective-c. The code I am using now is:

```
NSExpression *exp = [NSExpression expressionWithFormat: string];
NSNumber *result = [exp expressionValueWithObject:nil context:nil];
answer = [result stringValue];
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17287076/catching-nsinvalidargumentexception-from-nsexpression for an answer.

Comment: "3++2" is actually valid; it would mean "3 + +2", as opposed to "3 + -2"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think NSExpression is not the right tool for the job here. The class is part of the Cocoa predicate system and was designed to only accept well-formatted input.

I suggest you look for a proper math parser. I believe [GCMathParser](http://apptree.net/parser.htm) is a good choice. There's also [DDMathParser](https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser).

If you insist on using NSExpression, you can catch the exception like this:

```
@try {
  // the code that potentially raises an NSInvalidArgumentException
} @catch (NSException *exception) {
  if ([[exception name] isEqualToString:NSInvalidArgumentException]) {
    // your error handling
  }
}
```

Be advised, however, that this is bad practice. Exceptions in Objective-C should only be used to catch unexpected runtime errors. Your example does not qualify.

Comment: Any way to get around it using try catch blocks?

Comment: @user2303367 DDMathParser won't throw an exception, but it will also say that `3++2` is a valid expression (that evaluates to 5).