# iOS Swift Test for Valid Formula

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using this code to return the calculation of a string:

```
func calcString(txt: String) -> String {
    let expn = NSExpression(format: txt)
    var final: AnyObject = expn.expressionValueWithObject(nil, context: nil)
    return "\(final)"
}
```

How can I test that the string contains a valid formula?

Comment: What formula do you want to test ? What is it that you exactly want to do ?

Comment: I want to test if the mathematical formula contained in the string is a valid one.  For example, "(3+1))" would be invalid and I need to test for that so the app doesn't crash.

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSExpression catch invalid arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18421307/nsexpression-catch-invalid-arguments)  While your question isn't an exact duplicate (it's about swift which rules out try/catch) the gist of the answer is "You can't do it using `NSExpression`."

Comment: You can catch exceptions in Swift 2 now.