# Handling exception thrown by Foundation object?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, optional-parameters, foundation

I have a swift function to get the localized app name from the main bundle's `localizedInfoDictionary` with some fallback cases.

```
private func defaultAppName() -> String {
    var name: NSString = ""
    // Check for a localized version of the CFBundleDisplayName
    var mainBundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()
    // EXC_BAD_ACCESS HERE, despite the optional
    var mainBundleInfoDictionary: Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>? = mainBundle.localizedInfoDictionary

    if let infoDictionary = mainBundleInfoDictionary {
        name = infoDictionary["CFBundleDisplayName"] as NSString

        if (name.length == 0) {
            name = infoDictionary[kCFBundleNameKey] as NSString
        }
    }

    if (name.length == 0) {
        mainBundleInfoDictionary = mainBundle.infoDictionary

        if let infoDictionary = mainBundleInfoDictionary {
            name = infoDictionary["CFBundleDisplayName"] as NSString

            if (name.length == 0) {
                name = infoDictionary[kCFBundleNameKey] as NSString
            }
        }
    }

    return name
}
```

I know it's not concise, but I am still learning swift. The problem I am seeing is that accessing `mainBundle.localizedInfoDictionary` is not returning nil when not found, but rather throwing an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. I cannot guarantee that there will be a localized info in the apps where this function is used, yet the standard swift way of handling optionals is not working here.

How can I either catch the exception thrown by NSBundle's `localizedInfoDictionary` call or adapt my swift code to move on?

Comment: It seems that there currently is no solution for this problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24710424/catch-an-exception-for-invalid-user-input-in-swift for a similar problem, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24023112/try-catch-exceptions-in-swift.

Comment: Yeah, i didn't think there was a way to catch the exception. I am still interested in getting the localized name without it crashing though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, this is a bug in Swift and should be reported to bugreport.apple.com. This method used to return an implicit optional. They should have converted it to an explicit optional, but instead converted it to a non-optional since the method can return `nil`:

```
NSDictionary *mainBundleInfoDictionary = [[NSBundle mainBundle] localizedInfoDictionary];
NSLog(@"%@", mainBundleInfoDictionary);
```

But you don't generally need `localizedInfoDictionary`. You can just ask `NSBundle` directly:

```
private func defaultAppName() -> String {
  let mainBundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()
  let displayName = mainBundle.objectForInfoDictionaryKey("CFBundleDisplayName") as? String
  let name = mainBundle.objectForInfoDictionaryKey(kCFBundleNameKey) as? String
  return displayName ?? name ?? "Unknown"
}
```

Comment: Thanks! rdar://18332365

Comment: In modern Swift, the `let name =` not produces an ambiguous type error

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you get lucky by accessing the object directly? At least I had Playground behave better (without crashing) when doing it like this:

```
let name = mainBundle.objectForInfoDictionaryKey("CFBundleDisplayName") as? String
```

I know this does not directly address the localization problem. To also give an actionable suggestion, you could just make you own (duplicate) key in `Localizable.strings`.

Comment: This is going to be part of some open source software. I cannot guarantee that the implementor will have localized his/her app