# Handle NSInvalidArgumentException exception from NSExpression with Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I use NSExpression to solve math formulas. Everthing works fine, if the input formula is correct, but if I input a formula like:

```
6-
```

My app gets terminated with the following error message:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "6- == 1"'
```

In Object-C it is possible to put this code into a @try block. Is there something equal in swift? Or how do I handle this Exceptions?

Here is my simple NSExpression code:

```
let expression = NSExpression(format: finalFormula)

if let result = expression.expressionValueWithObject(nil, context: nil) as? NSNumber {
    return result
}
```

I solution would be to check the input first, but I would be OK for me if I get back nil or something like this.

Comment: Same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24710424/catch-an-exception-for-invalid-user-input-in-swift. It seems that a syntax error in the expression cannot be catched in Swift.

Comment: So it looks like I have to validate the input value first?

Comment: @patrickS were you able to find a proper solution other than manually validating the input yourself?