# How to get nil if something can't be evaluated?

Tags: swift, math, null, format, nsexpression

I am using NSExpression to solve strings from user input. 
Here is the code

```
var userInput = "5+"
var solveUserInput = NSExpression(format: "\(userInput)")
```

It will crash my program because it can't solve it, but what I want to do is to return nil if the string is unsolvable by NSExpression. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28005595/handle-nsinvalidargumentexception-exception-from-nsexpression-with-swift?lq=1) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24710424/catch-an-exception-for-invalid-user-input-in-swift).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSExpression is not really meant for that kind of usage (evaluation of user input).

I suggest that you have a look at [DDMathParser](https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser) instead.

Comment: That surprises me. I am using it in a small project of mine, with no problem.

Comment: If you want to look at it then go to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31168751/mathematical-parser-in-swift

Comment: Thanks for your comment up there because it helped me a lot

Comment: I guess your comment is ironic ;-) If you can reproduce the issue in a minimal Xcode project and publish the project somewhere, I will be happy to have a look at it.