# How to handle NSException error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

So, I've been making a basic calculator. But I've run into an issue.
[My code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPRul.png)

```
@IBAction func calculate(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let stringExpression = resultLabel.text!
    let expression = NSExpression(format: stringExpression)
    let result = expression.expressionValue(with: nil, context: nil) as! NSNumber
    resultLabel.text! = String(result.doubleValue) // Writes response on textLabel :D
}
```

The code above works. However, when a input such as 5++6 is entered it crashes my app. I'm not very sure how to deal with this.

The following error is shown when a invalid input is entered.
[The error given.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAa1q.png)
`libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)`

I'm not sure how I could make it display "Error".
And this should work for any type of error.

Comment: Copy/paste code or error message, do not show screenshots.

Comment: Fixed :) @Larme

Comment: And there is no explicit error message? Because I tried your code and got the real (and useful message): "*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "5++6 == 1"'" And it happens on "let expression = NSExpression(format: stringExpression)". That's real information to read and give about your issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Catch an exception for invalid user input in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24710424/catch-an-exception-for-invalid-user-input-in-swift)

Comment: That duplicate is for Swift 2.

Comment: @PranavRamesh The gist ist still true: You can't catch objc exceptions in swift. Use an objc wrapper that exposes standard objc error handling, usable in swift with do/try/catch.

Answer (score 0):

You *have to* pass a valid expression to the `NSExpression` initialiser or else it will throw an exception. There is no Swift-only way to catch exceptions so the only possibility for you is to make sure only valid input can be generated.

Comment: Or: ... to use an objc wrapper that adopts Swift's error handling.